# Escaping double double quotes in html attributes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, escaping

I use bootstrap and create html nodes which contain popovers with jQuery. The popovers contain html so that I have problems with the quotes and escaping:

```
var content = '<input type="text" ng-model="test1" />';
var txt =     '<button type="button" data-container="body" ' +
                     'data-toggle="popover" title="myTitle" data-html="true" '+
                     'data-content="'+content+'">Click</button>';
```

How can I escape the double quotes inside the attributes => html-attributes? in the data-content attribute correctly?

**Edit:** I compile the code with angular so that it should also work with it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If it is HTML, you can use HTML entities to escape characters that might be interpreted otherwise. For example, `&quot;` will be displayed as `"` in HTML attributes:

```
var content = '<input type=&quot;text&quot; ng-model=&quot;test1&quot; />';
```

Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/5X5Ye/

Refer to W3C's HTML entities chart for more information: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: this works in general but not with angular compiling

Comment: @zoidbergi "doesn't work with angular compiling" That's a rather nebulous description. What doesn't work? What error do you get? **Also, it helps to specify beforehand** that you're using AngularJS. It wasn't mentioned anywhere in your question.

Comment: Yes, I thought it would work with angular anyway. This was false.

Comment: This works within Angular's compiled expressions. For instance, title="{{last_modified | date : &quot;EEE, MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mma&quot;}}"